# How To Create Array Of SKSpriteNodes? (swift, spritekit)

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I have 12 ball sprites all of which have the same attributes. Is it possible to put them all in an array so I dont have to keep typing....

```
      ball1.size.......
      ball2.size........
      ball3.size......
```

Etc.

I would like to create an array called allBalls and then just change every ball through one line of code like shown...

```
      allBalls.size.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array of `SKSpriteNode`s you could do the following:

```
let allBalls = [ball1, ball2, ball3] // Of type Array<SKSpriteNode>
```

Then iterate through the array and change the `size` property of each ball:

```
for ball in allBalls {
    ball.size = // Whatever size you want.
}
```