# How to create an array of SKSpriteNodes using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite, skspritenode

I've designed my program so that each time the user touches the screen, the sprite's image and position changes. I want to be able to make an array of SKSpriteNodes. I've seen a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879848/how-to-create-array-of-skspritenodes-swift-spritekitclass), but they used a for-in loop. Is it possible to create a SKSpriteNode at initialization?

```
GameScene: SKScene {
    // make an array of images that you will possibly change in the future

    // calls the image
    let dad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dad0")
    var imageName = "dad"

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-10, y:0 , duration: 0.01)
```

...assuming that I already placed dad sprite node onto screen...

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        // when index is zero, sprite is dad0. 
        // Change image to dad1 (lifted leg), don't change position     
        if index == 0{
            index += 1 //image names are dad0, dad1
            imageName += "\(index)"
            print(imageName)
            dad.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:imageName)
        }
        else{
            index += 1
            imageName += "\(index)"
            print(imageName)
            dad.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:imageName)
            //moves dad
            dad.runAction(moveLeft) // moves image
            index = 0
        }
        //change the image name back to dad
        imageName = "dad"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of `SKSpriteNode` could be simply: `[SKSpriteNode]` (Array in swift composed by elements of `SKSpriteNode` type)

So , everytime you want to add a new SKSpriteNode you can do it with:

```
var arraySprites :[SKSpriteNode] = [SKSpriteNode]()

let dad : SKSpriteNode! 

dad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dad0")

arraySprites.append(dad)
```

Comment: thanks! I initialized the array and the images inside the class, then append dad to the array inside of the didMoveToView function